# Webcam not working in Acer laptop

Tags: webcam, acer

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer One Aspire 756-967BCkk laptop. But my webcam is not working. Programs like Cheese or Skype can't detect my camera.

Comment: Cant detect or there is only black when you open those programs?

Answer (score 0):

Is the webcam switched on? On my net book (MSI Wind clone) I have to put the camera on using the keyboard shortcut and then open Cheese or Skype and then it is recognised.